# Using subquery in where clause

Tags: mysql

I have a subquery that looks like this:

```
    SELECT field1, (
      SELECT date2
      FROM table2
      ORDER BY date2 DESC
    ) AS last_contacted
    FROM table1
    ORDER BY last_contacted DESC
```

However, I'm getting records where `last_contacted` is NULL. I don't want these in the results so I thought `WHERE last_contacted IS NOT NULL` but that returns the error:

`Unknown column 'last_contacted' in 'where clause'`

So how can I remove those from the results?

Comment: Replace `WHERE` with `HAVING`

Answer (score 0):

One can  use column aliases in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses.

Refer the mysql documenation.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT field1, (
  SELECT date2
  FROM table2
  ORDER BY date2 DESC
) AS last_contacted
FROM table1
HAVING last_contacted NOT NULL
ORDER BY last_contacted DESC
```